# is possible in solr to create a facet with multiple values? please see details

Tags: search, solr

I have field called articleType. One article can have one or more types. now I want to create a facet e.g. type_facet which will have all the values of "type" column for article. I.E it will be taking more than one values from single column, any ideas how is it possible?

I know facet can be multivalued, but that only works when facet is copying data from different fields.

below is the config for facet.

```
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="type_facet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

and then i am copying this type value to facet.

```
<copyField source="type" dest="type_facet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable out of the box. Change the articleType field to have a type that uses the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory tokenizer for the index (probably called something like `textgen` or something in the defaulr Solr installation). Then put all applicable article types separated by a space in that field of the article document. When you facet by that field then, it will return you all such values. If your article types are multiword, then you'll have to use multivalued fields and facet on those. Again, it should just work.